# Matlab m-file compilation

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I need to compile a matlab m-file , `file.m` .
I also want to add some helper files and shared resources which are in folders

```
c:\tt\folder1\    
c:\tt\folder2\
```

I can easily do this using the deploytool option in matlab. But I want to be able to do this using the matlab commandline. After some searches, I found the following code

```
mcc -m  file.m -I C:\tt\folder1 -I C:\tt\folder2
```

but this is not doing anything. Matlab just goes into 'busy mode'.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong??...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mcc -m  file.m -a C:\tt\folder1 -a C:\tt\folder2
```

Comment: Thanks! this is working fine. An additional question though:Is there a way to suppress the command line output that runs with the compiled exe?